# Idiomatic Option<T> to Option<U> when T -> U is defined with From

Tags: rust

Given two arbitrary Sized types `T` and `U`, where `U: From<T>`, is there a reason why standard library does not provide `From<Option<T>> for Option<U>` with a `where U: From<T>`?  I tried to do it, but get a conflicting implementation error, so clearly there is a limitation, just not sure where.  And yes, I understand I can do it with a `Option::map()`, but it seems like std should give this out of the box.

```rust
enum Opt<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}

impl<T: From<U>, U> From<Opt<T>> for Opt<U> {
    fn from(opt: Opt<T>) -> Self {
        match opt {
            Opt::Some(t) => Opt::Some(t.into()),
            Opt::None => Opt::None,
        }
    }
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(_: A) -> Self {
        B
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Opt::Some(A);
    let _b: Opt<B> = a.into();
}
```

Error

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<Opt<_>>` for type `Opt<_>`
 --> src/bin/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | impl<T: From<U>, U> From<Opt<T>> for Opt<U> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

Comment: The usual way of making this conversion is either `a.map(A::Into)` or `a.map(B::From)`. (The question alludes to using `map()`; just wanted to make this more explicit for the convenience of future visitors.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason, because it conflicts with the `impl<T> From<T> for T` as you've noticed in case `T == U`. Just like you can't write this impl, std can't either (even the current specialization doesn't support this, and specialization isn't used for public interfaces). There is a desire for such impl (and similar impls for other types), it's just not clear how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Chayim, do you know any relevant discussions or RFCs on how the compiler could be made to support such cases? Also, I have heard of the specialization efforts, but not certain why that wouldn't apply in this case?

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan I don't think an RFC with a concrete idea was ever suggested. More like ideas floating around in the https://internals.rust-lang.org/ forum. And about specialization, it can only specialize currently if the impl is strictly more specialized, that is, a strict subset of the other impl, not in the general case of colliding implementations.

Comment: What would i search for in order to find a discussion of such specialization?  Is there a particular name of non-more-specialized specialization? :)

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan I don't think there is any special name for it. The discussions are mainly on IRLO.